# promoting your question by intentionally making duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just marked [my own meta question as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335294/promoting-product-vs-just-an-answer). It got me wondering, someone could use this to promote his other questions. Of course this would be useful for readers (not the person who made the original question) preparing to ask that specific question in a duplicate-like way, but get stopped in their tracks, because the creator already made that dupe.

My problem is that this type of behavior strikes me as "spam"-y.

Like imagine if someone decided to create say 30 different questions that are duplicates of just one question with different accounts. The creator flags all of them as duplicates. His original gets much more exposure (which is good to readers), but much more votes too (which is just flat out extortion of SE's flagging system)

So the question is, is this acceptable? Can SE prevent this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange is moderated by a community of users, and the community is given an unprecedented level of transparency regarding who is posting what. And with that, users are also given the *tools* to express an approval/disapproval of what is being posted.

So (in your example) if you were to post "spam"-y duplicates simply to cross-link to your own posts, the community would almost certainly notice… and they would likely down-vote those posts systemically (among other remedial actions like flagging such content for further investigation).

**So how does that stop the activity?**

When you have multiple closed posts (spurred by this example), the system would automatically generate a flag for "multiple closed posts…" prompting a Moderator to investigate further. "Consistently low quality questions over time" can also prompt a Moderator to contact the user privately to raise these concerns and to offer specific guidance about how to improve their experience.  And if the user gets enough down-votes, the system will automatically block the user from posting any further until their *existing* content can be improved.

This is just *one* example of how the community — *collectively*  — keeps such shenanigans under control.

Comment: So, technically if the creator creates several different accounts using the same IP address, and uses really good word play, and creates duplicates questions under these accounts that mean the same thing, but are worded entirely differently, they can do that? That seems kind of "unsafe"...

Comment: @DaMaxContent if the sock puppets would create content that looks like genuine and good quality this would mean [mission accomplished](https://xkcd.com/810/). You got to understand that no one is interested to dive deep into investigating who is who as long as content looks OK, search for cumbersome details of potential sock puppets starts when content feels not OK

Comment: DaMax, We also have tools to catch sockpuppets (someone posing as multiple users), but geeeez ... we're talking about a *lot* of effort for a diminishingly small gain. It's not 100% iron clad, but all you have to do is make it "not worth it" and that's what makes broad-based moderation *work.*